# jQuery: Trying to create a login page that only redirects when the username and password is correct

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, authentication

I'm trying to create a login page that only redirects to the feed if the username and password is correct, otherwise it will alert('Incorrect username or password'). However, if the input information is correct, it still alerts the user that the password is incorrect, before loading the feed.

```
window.onload = () => {
  const usernameAndPassword = {
    nicole: "password",
    james: "austin",
    john: "terrio",
  };

  $(document).ready(() => {
    $(".login-button").click(() => {
      const username = $("#username").val();
      const password = $("#password").val();

      for (let key in usernameAndPassword) {
        if ((usernameAndPassword[username] === password)) {
          $(location).attr("href", "./feed.html");
          break;
        } else {
          alert("Incorrect username or password");
        }
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: usernameAndPassword[username] === password

Comment: Thank you! I noticed that when I posted too, but after I changed it, it's now still alerting the user if the username/password is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need loop

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const usernameAndPassword = {
    nicole: "password",
    james: "austin",
    john: "terrio",
  };
  $(document).ready(() => {
    $(".login-button").click(() => {
      const username = $("#username").val();
      const password = $("#password").val();
      if (usernameAndPassword[username]=== password) {
           console.log("redirect here")       
      }
      else{
         console.log("wrong pass");
      }
    });
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="username" type="text" />
<input id="password" type="text" />
<button class="login-button">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `if` statement you refer to the object, not the array, so you should do it that way:

```
usernameAndPassword.key === password
```

Comment: There is no property `key`, did you mean `usernameAndPassword[key]`?